# #Value in my custom function

Tags: vba, excel

I inhereited a custom function on one of my sheets.  Its basically doing a strightline interp on 1 of 3 tables depending on bunch of variables.  Some reason everytime i open another workbook all my outputs turn into #Value errors.  If i reset the macro then it works.  Weird.  Please help!

```
Function INTERP(A, CURVENUM)

COL1 = CURVENUM * 3 - 2
COL2 = COL1 + 1


NUMPOINTS = Range("INV").Cells(-1, COL2)
'A = 80
MAXINV = Range("INV").Cells(1, COL1)
MININV = Range("INV").Cells(NUMPOINTS, COL1)

If A >= MAXINV Then
M = (Range("INV").Cells(2, COL2) - Range("INV").Cells(1, COL2)) / (Range("INV").Cells(2, COL1) - Range("INV").Cells(1, COL1))
Q = Range("INV").Cells(1, COL2) - (Range("INV").Cells(1, COL1) - A) * M
End If

If A <= MININV Then
M = (Range("INV").Cells(NUMPOINTS, COL2) - Range("INV").Cells(NUMPOINTS - 1, COL2)) / (Range("INV").Cells(NUMPOINTS, COL1) - Range("INV").Cells(NUMPOINTS - 1, COL1))
Q = (A - Range("INV").Cells(NUMPOINTS, COL1)) * M + Range("INV").Cells(NUMPOINTS, COL2)
End If


For I = 1 To NUMPOINTS - 1
X1 = Range("INV").Cells(I, COL1)
X2 = Range("INV").Cells(I + 1, COL1)

If A <= X1 And A > X2 Then
N2 = Range("INV").Cells(I + 1, COL2)
N1 = Range("INV").Cells(I, COL2)
D2 = Range("INV").Cells(I + 1, COL1)
D1 = Range("INV").Cells(I, COL1)
M = (N2 - N1) / (D2 - D1)  'SLOPE

Q = N2 - (D2 - A) * M
INTERP = Q
Exit Function
End If

Next I

If A = MAXINV Then Q = Range("INV").Cells(NUMPOINTS, COL2)

INTERP = Q

End Function
```

Comment: A shot in the dark. What happens if you fully qualify your range objects? for example `Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("INV")`

Comment: Do you mean declare it like this Dim INV As Range Set INV = Worksheets("Data Table").Range("A7:B13")
or
insert it over in the code itself?

Comment: `Dim INV As Range` and then `Set INV = Worksheets("Data Table").Range("A7:B13")` and then replace `Range("INV")` everywhere else with `INV`. For example `Range("INV").Cells(1, COL1)` becomes `INV.Cells(1, COL1)`

Comment: Or you can use `With INV - End With` and put all the code inside it.

Comment: I did that and no go.  I even replaced all "INV" with the Worksheets("Data Table").Range("A7:B13") as well and no luck.  been really stumped on this one.

Comment: `I inhereited a custom function on one of my sheets` Sheets? Or is the function in module? Also did you try stepping through it?

Comment: I can step through a custom function? and yes function is in the module

Comment: Yes you can. But don't believe me till you try it ;)

Comment: F8 right?  Debug/Stepinto  yeah its not doing anything.  How would that work?  does it do the calculations in a seperate window or something?

Comment: no. place the cursor on function name and press `F9`. Now go to any cell which has that function and then press `F2` and then the `Enter`

Comment: I'm having trouble moving through the code.  do i just keep pushing enter?  Sorry for the boneheaded questions, it's blowing my mind that i can step into a function right now

Comment: May I see your excel file? if yes, can you upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here. If it has some confidential info then please remove that or replace it with dummy data before uploading.

Comment: [URL=http://wikisend.com/download/321206/Calc with Dummy Data_Coding Purposes.xlsm]Calc with Dummy Data_Coding Purposes.xlsm[/URL]

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/321206/Calc with Dummy Data_Coding Purposes.xlsm

Thanks for all the help.  gotta run into a meeting will check back in 1.5 hours

Comment: strange i am unable to reproduce the error. It is working just fine on my end.

Comment: try opening another workbook with macros.  it should bomb out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with this function:

1) It will look for Range("Inv") in whatever happens to be the active workbook (which will change when you open another workbook). change all your references to Range("Inv") to Application.caller.parent.parent.Names("Inv").ReferstoRange

2) your function will not recalculate when INV changes unless you make the function volatile or add INV as a parameter to the function

Comment: Totally worked! You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. I just want to get this straight so basically it was looking for the named range "INV" in my new workbook which doesn't exist thus giving me the error. and Application.caller.parent.parent.Names("Inv").ReferstoRange allows me to keep the range in my current workbook.

Comment: Yes: the parent of the parent of the calling range is the calling workbook that contains the INV Named Range. An alternative solution would be to pass the INV range in as a parameter to the function (this would also solve potential problem number 2, and would allow INV to be in a different workbook.)